# How can I install MinGW-w64 on windows 10?

Tags: windows, mingw-w64

Can’t install MinGW-w64 on my operating system(windows 10). The new MinGW-w64 version doesn’t come with a bin folder.
Please i need help using the compiler.

Comment: does this link help you https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

Answer (score 1):

A Little late.
For Windows 10/11.

1. go to GitHub repository: https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases
2. choose what you need and download: https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases/download/12.2.0-rt_v10-rev2/x86_64-12.2.0-release-posix-seh-msvcrt-rt_v10-rev2.7z
3. unzip and copy the repository.
   3.1 Make a directory where you want it installed e.g.: `C:\MinGW64`
   3.2 Copy all the directories inside unzipped "mingw64" to `C:\MinGW64`
4. Add the environment variable Path.
   4.1 Windows Search type "Environment Variables"
   Environment Variables / System variables
   Click in "Path" and select edit
   Click New and Put the route to Bin e.g.: `"C:\MinGW64\bin"` -> Click OK.
5. Test if everything are ok, CMD: `C:\\{some_path}\gcc.exe --version`